# Speech to Text: Identifying sanskrit slokas from audio file

Tags: python, audio, split, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am trying to identify the start and end location of **slokas** from an audio file, I used assembly AI to convert the audio into text using "assembly AI" but the conversion is not very good:

```
import assemblyai as aai
from assemblyai import TranscriptionConfig, LanguageCode


def transcribe(audio_filepath, output_filepath):
    config = TranscriptionConfig(language_code=LanguageCode.hi)
    transcriber = aai.Transcriber(config=config)
    transcript = transcriber.transcribe(audio_filepath)

    with open(output_filepath, 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(transcript.json_response))
```

The challenge is the words in slokas are in Sanskrit whereas the majority of the parts in the audio is in hindi, and apart from slokas it's able to identify the rest of the text very well.

My objective is to be able to identify the start and end locations of such slokas and clip the audio part out of it, right now I have 100+ lectures and doing it manually is laborious, so wanted to check if anyone has any better ideas of

Comment: Ah, I see. The speech is code-switching between Hindi and Sanskrit, and the model you are using is for Hindi only. Is there an ability to fine-tune the model, or to add custom vocabulary, and that way you could add the `slokas` word to the custom vocabulary?